# Refactoring an app written in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, security, refactoring, tapku

I need to refactor an app, written long time ago. As a begginer, I'm struggling a little bit with a bunch of new question.
It was written in objective C.
It has included some frameworks (security, coredata, quartzcore, mapkit...) and application uses tapku library. That's what I know so far.
There is an XmlRpc external there. My question is: If that all is written in 2014. from some random guy, do I need to change/upgrade all of this frameworks/external etc. and find a newer version of it on the internet, or I can use it as they are?

Edit: I'm rewriting the whole project, I need to fix things that are not working, (I didn't find any still, though) and I'm just asking if I would have benefits (speed of application, user experience etc.) if I include a newer version of all of these frameworks, if that is possible.

Comment: Your question is too broad and not clear if are you rewriting the whole project or just to add new features and maintenance you are going to add within existing project!

Comment: Try to stay at the same versions. Update if you found issues in libraries.